# AWS - Terraform Workspace failing to run in different region

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm working with Terraform workspace to build in multiple regions; however, I've encountered an issue trying to run the same code in a second region. I have no issues running the code in us-east-1, my primary region, but when I run it in a different region, I get the following error:

```
│ Error: error configuring Terraform AWS Provider: no valid credential sources for Terraform AWS Provider found.
│ 
│ Please see https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws
│ for more information about providing credentials.
│ 
│ Error: InvalidClientTokenId: The security token included in the request is invalid.
│       status code: 403, request id: xxx
│   with provider["registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws"],
│   on main.tf line 4, in provider "aws":
│    4: provider "aws" {
```

My provider section in main.tf looks like this:

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "${var.region}"
  profile = var.profile
}
```

I'm using config and credentials in the .aws folder for authentication. In my config file, I'm assuming a role, and referencing a source profile in the credentials file. Though using the same profile, which i'm referencing from a variable file, I have no issues running against one region, but do on the second region. However, if I was to use an account specific for the account I'm assuming the role for, I have no issues running the code.

What am I missing, that it runs successfully for one region but the second is failing with same profile?

Comment: A random guess - do you have the other region enabled in your AWS account?

Comment: What region are you trying to run it in ? "No valid credentials" sounds like you aren't authenticated. What does `aws sts get-caller-identity` return for each region ?

Comment: Sorry, for the delay in my response..holidays and all. But I was able to get it working though not sure why, in my provider module, instead of referencing the region as a variable from a variable file, I need to input an actual value, i.e. us-east-1. Once I did that I could change workspaces and run the terrafom plan successful against the different regions. Is there a way to use the region variable instead of having an actual value in region.

Comment: Update to my previous comment, it seems I was mistaken, if I manually enter the 2nd region in the provider module, it fails with same issue. I'm definitely missing something and not seeing why I'm getting this error.  I've run ```aws sts get-caller-identity --profile xxxxx --region eu-south-1```, and get the following error, An error occurred (InvalidClientTokenId) when calling the GetCallerIdentity operation: The security token included in the request is invalid. But using us-east-1 region in the same command I get a valid output.

Comment: Another update, I was able to get the command, ```aws sts get-caller-identity --profile xxxxx --region eu-south-1``` to run successfully now, and I'm able to to run cli in both region; however, terraform is still complaining with the same error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue has been resolved. As I was using an assumed role for another account, I discovered that the region was not enabled on the main account. Once I had enabled the region in AWS, I was able to successfully run terraform on the region.